What does "hairy business" mean?
In this clip from the movie Poor Things (2023), there's the line "She grabbed my hairy business!", but I can not find any definition of "hairy business" on the internet.
I guess it means "hairy thing" which refers to genitals, but it might mean something else.
Also, When do we say it?
ChatGPT says: The phrase "hairy business" typically refers to a task or situation that is complex, challenging, or difficult to handle.

I’m voting to close this question because it's obviously a one-off humorous coinage, where my hairy business just means my pubic area. ...compare my hairy bits.

ChatGPT is referring to the slang meaning of hairy as 'alarming, worrying' as in "Riding my bike down that steep hill was a bit hairy".

a hairy business = a tense / scary situation. Partly alliteration, and partly an allusion to hair standing up when you're cold and/or frightened. Not relevant to the cited usage.

But I was amused to find Your hairy business is a muff cited (not apparently coined) by Jonathon Swift in a riddle back in the 1700s. I thought that use of muff was relatively modern, but the full OED has it from 1699 with definition I.2.a (slang) muff The female pubic hair. Hence also: the vulva, the vagina.

@FumbleFingers, if you can show the website or any dictionary that defines "hairy business", I will close this question

It won't be defined in any dictionary. Google books has no instances of his hairy business, my hair business, or her hairy business, and the only instance of your hairy business is the above cite from mid-1700s. It's not an established collocation in this sense. But you won't even find a hairy business (tense situation) defined in dictionaries - you have to use normal principles of language to join hairy = scary, tense and business =  situation, matter.

The clip is from last year's Poor Things movie, where the central character Bella is a sort of "erotic Frankenstein's monster" brought back to life by an eccentric Victorian surgeon who replaced her brain with that of an infant. Consequently, Bella has to learn English from scratch, and she's not very good at it. It's partly played for laughs - when Bella discovers the joy of sex, for example, she calls it furious jumping. It's not a movie from which you might hope to learn much about normal current English!

(Answer copied from a flagged comment.)

hairy business is slang that can refer to a dangerous, risky, or daunting job. Collins defines hairy as "exciting, worrying, and somewhat frightening" and "business" has among its meanings a colloquial meaning of "any task, especially one that can have complications".

Neutralizing bombs is hairy business.
Washing windows a hundred storeys up is hairy business.
That roller coaster is one of the scariest I've ever been on. That last turn was really hairy.
At this point you must carefully remove the inner spring, but take care, as it's easily dropped and can fall down inside the chamber and you'll never get it out again. Don't ask me how I know. It's hairy business.


This definition is completely unrelated to the example in OP's video clip.

I understand that. Responding to this comment: if you can show ... any dictionary that defines "hairy business", I will close this question  I didn't watch the video.  Don't want "hairy business" ads popping up whenever I visit a website that uses ads for revenue.

I think the OP is expecting (more accurately, requesting) a single definition for the actual collocation hairy business - with the meaning as used in Poor Things (2023)

“Business” can mean “any activity or objective needing to be dealt with; especially, one of a financial or legal matter” like “that whole business with Amber Heard”.
“Hairy” can mean “frightening” or “dangerous” — I assume harkening to hairy, scary animals, since the expression “hair-raising” is much more recent.
So “hairy business” could mean a frightening activity.
In context, though, I think the “hairy” is meant literally, furnished with hair, and “business” means “something involving one personally”, as in “Mind your own business”.
Taken together, “hairy business” would mean one’s genitals, which is what the clip shows.
